# Python regex that separates to words unless it is inside quotes

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to achieve this:

Input:

```
Hi, Are you happy? I am "extremely happy" today
```

Output:

```
['Hi,', 'Are', 'you', 'happy?', 'I', 'am', 'extremely happy', 'today']
```

Is there a straight-forward approach to achieve this? I tried using another pattern I found:

```
pattern = r'"([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)"'
```

I assume this should find the text inside the quote, but did not manage to find a way to nail it.

**EDIT**

I also tried splitting using the next regex, but this obviously only gives me spaces separation which cuts my text inside quotes to segments:

```
            tokens = [token for token in re.split(r"(\W)", text) if token.strip()]
```

Is there a way to combine the pattern I supplied with this for loop such that it return an array that each word in a different cell unless it is quoted and then whats inside the quotes gets its own cell?

Comment: What if there is `'I am"extremely happy" today"'`?

Comment: I have prior knowledge it will not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) instead of regex

```
import shlex

print(shlex.split('input: Hi, Are you happy? I am "extremely happy" today'))
```

result:

```
['input:', 'Hi,', 'Are', 'you', 'happy?', 'I', 'am', 'extremely happy', 'today']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fun way to do it: First split on quotes, then split every non-quoted part (every other):

```
str = 'I am "super happy" today'

ss = str.split('"')

res = sum(([w] if i%2 else w.split() for i,w in enumerate(ss)), [])
```

To remove punctuation, you need to replace split() on last line with a proper regexp, but I think you had that covered already.

This will not remove punctuation inside quotes of course, and you cannot nest quotes. So you cannot be "super "super" happy" :)

Comment: Slight simplification to the code. I noticed that a string starting with a quoted part creates an empty first item in ss, so quoted parts are always odd items in ss, regardless of where quotes appear.